# Is there any plugin for course management?

Tags: plugins

I have wordpress site for a school or college.

My requirement is I need Classes like (from one class to 8th class) and then classes will have courses/subjects(like physics, Maths etc) and then each course has a file to upload.

The teacher will upload the file to a course and then the student will download the file of a course from the front end.

The teacher will add classes, courses to classes and can upload the files to the courses.

The student can only download the files uploaded for a course.

SO Is there any plugin of wordpress to do work for me or I have to write my own?

Any help and suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a buddypress addon called Courseware but it means you need the whole buddypress package.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-courseware/

It might be doing too much though, and potentially you'll have a lot of CSS to write / templates to edit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly meet your requirements, but if you use the [Omni Secure Files](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/omni-secure-files/) (OSF) plugin it will give you a Folders / Files implementation with the ability to upload files. They're half way to fully implementing permissions for the directories.

You can then split out your school years / classes by directory and upload the files to the corresponding directory.

I used this plugin and did quite a lot of modifications to it and combined it with the [Role Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/role-manager/) plugin. I've given a wordpress capability to each OSF directory (so each time you create a folder you add a capability called `osf_directory_{id}`) - you can then filter the page that displays the folders on whether `current_user_can('osf_directory_{id}')`.

If I get a chance I'll post up a link to my code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe S2 Member would help. It is a free plugin with a premium upgrade option. Otherwise Wishlist Member (which is premium plugin allows complete control over content.